# Multiple attachment field in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.2

I am using sitecore 8.2.

I need to add two fields of attachment type in one template. But when I attach file in one field, same value is getting copied in another field of attachment type. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The attachment field must be named "Blob" and if that still holds true, you can can only have 1 attachment field per template.  If you have multiple then they will all need to be named "Blob" and therefore will all be hydrated with the same value.

I found the name restriction in this article about the field in Siteocre 6.6
http://blogs.perficient.com/digitaltransformation/2012/12/05/working-with-the-sitecore-attachment-field-type/